# Variable change to solve by transform Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have the next differential equation

---

\begin{eqnarray}
 A\frac{dh}{dt}=-\sqrt{2gh}; \hspace{2cm} h(0)=h_{0}
\end{eqnarray}
Where $A,h_{0},g$ are positive constants,so I need to pass this differential equation to a linear and solve by Laplace transform but I can't see some apropiate variable change for this. I was trying to resolve the original differential equation, this solution is

---

\begin{eqnarray}
 h(t)=h_{0}-\frac{\sqrt{2gh_{0}}}{A}t+\frac{g}{2A}t^{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Do you know some variable change, to convert this non-linear differential equation to a linear? Thank you for your comments or hint.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I solve this differential equation with that initial condition by Laplce transform. This solution is equivalent to the solution for original equation?

Comment: Set $h=u^2$, then the resulting equation is linear, after dividing by $u$. But that is then a simple integration, no need for a Laplace transform.